# issues with gcc compilation on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

My gcc installation was working fine, but recently something broke and I am not sure what broke it. How do I go about fixing this? This is the message I get on trying to compile hello world in C.

```
$ gcc hello.c 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/cc1: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v717/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libppl_c.so.4)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/cc1: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v717/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libppl.so.12)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v717/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6
```

You have a locally installed, likely outdated, `libstdc++.so.6` on your system, which has somehow got itself registered in `ldconfig` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or whatever it's called this week. You cannot run programs linked against your normal system `libstdc++.so.6` until you get rid of that library. gcc itself is linked against `libstdc++.so.6` so it cannot run too.

Comment: Cleaning up the LD_LIBRARY_PATH did it. It had a bunch of paths to ...MATLAB... from an install that did not complete.